# How do I pass an environment variable to a CGI script by simply placing its value immediately after the slash after the domain?

Tags: perl, url, cgi, url-routing, environment-variables

I would like to pass an environment variable to a cgi script written in perl by including it as the only text after the first slash after the domain name in the url.  For example, typically one might do this like so:  `http://www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/my_perl_script.pl?my_environment_variable=12345`.  I would like it to look like this instead:  `http://wwww.mydomain.com/12345`.  How do I do that?  I would like persistent access to this value as the user navigates my site.  I would be happy to pass it around as a hidden form input, or write a cookie.  This is purely for aesthetic purposes and to make the urls easier to remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Apache (as I am) you should use the mod_rewrite module.  Behold:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
    RewriteRule     ([^(cgi\-bin\/my_perl_script\.pl)]+) /cgi-bin/my_perl_script.pl?my_environment_variable=$1  [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Glad you got an answer, still more modern things than CGI exist (and can run under CGI!). I am a big fan of [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) myself, but Dancer and Web::Simple (or even Catalyst) can handle requests like this easily. I highly recommend trying something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `CGI.pm` module, you can use the `url()` method to obtain [the URL used to access the script](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#OBTAINING-THE-SCRIPTS-URL). Turn `-path` and `-rewrite` on to get the complete path.

You can then parse it however you like ([the URI module](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) is a good choice).

Such:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use URI;
use Try::Tiny;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $id = "a default value";

try {
    my $uri = URI->new($cgi->url(-rewrite=>1, -path=>1));
    my $path = $uri->path;
    my @parts = split '/', $path;
    $id = pop @parts;
};

print $cgi->header('text/plain');
say $id;
```

Comment: I assume any dependence on the CGI or URI modules would not preclude my ability to convert my scripts to use FastCGI or mod_perl in the future?

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJuniorShabadoo — It could cause some issues. I'd recommend [Plack](http://plackperl.org/), which abstracts those sort of differences away.

Comment: There's one more thing needed.  When I enter the url http://www.mydomain.com/12345 I get a 404 response saying 12345 not found.  I have modified my .htaccess file to run a cgi script if the user navigates to http://www.mydomain.com, however, how do I make it run that script for http://www.mydomain.com/anyvaluehere?